Broken ground conductor in single wire earth return (SWER) system
I have a property in a rural area that is serviced by a SWER line. This means we get one high voltage line from the utility into the service transformer, whose other leg is connected directly to ground. The secondary has a center tap which is connected to the same ground as the primary and that forms the neutral wire coming into my property, alongside two other live wires.
What happens if the ground connection between the transformer and the ground is severed? My understanding is this would send high voltage directly to my neutral conductor, through my utility box, and into my grounding system, possibly creating a step voltage inside my property. This would happen since the primary and the secondary's grounds are tied together at the transformer and a single wire comes down to ground the whole thing.
Even if ground isn't totally broken at the transformer, if for some reason I get a lower resistance to ground through my property than the pole has I'd still see some current flowing through it, right?

" and into my grounding system,"  This indicates to me that you do have an additional, local, ground connection (like one or more long copper rods) driven into the actual ground near your electrical service entrance.  This is good.  Also, just because the grounded conductors have zero, or low, potential, doesn't mean that there are no currents running in those conductors.  When dealing with this stuff, one should always assume that large currents are flowing in grounded conductors.  What is the distance from your transformer to the property's service entrance?

The distance from the transformer to the property's service entrance is about 10-15 meters, and yes I do have two copper rods driven into the ground at my service entrance. My concern is exactly about getting step voltage around them -- if they were to conduct a significant amount of current.

Correcting my previous comment, the distance from the transformer to the property's service entrance is closer to 60 meters.

I am not an electrician. In addition to the neutral being bonded at the transformer, Is the neutral also bonded to ground near your service entrance (and possibly any out-buildings)?  What is your general location?

No, it's only bonded to ground at the transformer and in my utility box close to the meter. I'm in Brazil.
